# Typescript generics - use interfaces keys for another key type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

It is kinda hard to explain what i want to achieve (not sure if it is possible) so here it the code:

```
interface CellConfig {
  btn?: cellBtn;
  ...
}
```

```
interface CellBtn {
  isEnabled?: boolean;
  label?: string;
  style?: any;
  classes?: any;
}
```

```
interface DataSet {
  position: number;
  name: string;
  weight: string;
  symbol: string;
  config?: *missing part, not sure how to do it*
}
```

so i want to have something like this:

```
let dataSet: DataSet = {
  position: 1,
  name: 'test',
  weight: '11',
  symbol: '123',
  config: { position: { btn: {isEnabled: true }}, name: { btn: { isEnabled: true }}}
}
```

basically, config should be optional object and only DataSet keys are allowed (except config) and also each key in config object should be of type CellConfig

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Answer (score 3):

For ease of constructing `DataSet`, I'd probably split out the interface into the non-`config` properties like this:

```
interface BaseDataSet {
    position: number;
    name: string;
    weight: string;
    symbol: string;
}
```

And then make `DataSet` extend it with a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `config` property:

```
interface DataSet extends BaseDataSet {
    config?: { [K in keyof BaseDataSet]?: CellConfig }
}
```

You can verify that this behaves as expected for your example.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIQDYYEJhMgbwFgAoZc5YAZwFEQ4AjDCAEwH4AuZBgex+bggA3KQrIMjTJ2RUwUUAHMRZCrICezaYLXKxCCVSoQqWkDtIBfUqVCRYiFOiyoeIGMAWFRFBnmlOcPGUrEhtwaHgkZGw4IwARODA4AGUIMC8VcgAHHipgMGBXLhAAVwBbBmhdCnoyiC5ZeRAlb3IAdwgPAAswBrlFavIqNQr+PqaWkhCwu0iUBKTU9IgAD0gQFipo2IgFlLSMvVd3BWkCZABtAGlKfABrCDUeGG34xP2wAF1-TAwXNw8yBC0xIzHSLHeSy4eyWyAAvIcKDk8gUisgAIwAGlayFq9WQAHJILICdjMsgOt1eoT0ejSTjhqMMFwCeiAEwAZnp5IQxw8XHOyPyhRAAu4eDF1DojGYLC4chKKAsQMxuLgdTFvlFhEotHoTFY8qgiqBpuBQA)

Answer (score 1):

> This is a more convoluted way of @jcalz answer that avoids making a new type (though at the cost of readability)

Since you are using `interface`s, you can use `this` to access the full type, then exclude `config` using `Exclude<keyof this, "config">` to get the type sans `config`, make an object of `CellConfig`s using `Record<keyof Exclude<keyof this, "config">, CellConfig>` and make all optional using `Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof this, "config">, CellConfig>>`:

```
interface DataSet {
  position: number;
  name: string;
  weight: string;
  symbol: string;
  config?: Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof this, "config">, CellConfig>>;
}
```